ssues with simultaneous pressing of left and middle mouse buttons
I am working on a project that uses the Fabric.js library to create an interactive canvas. I have a rectangle on the canvas that can be moved by dragging with the left mouse button.
I have noticed that, if I hold down the left mouse button to move the rectangle and then press the middle mouse button, the rectangle 'sticks' to the mouse, even if I release the left mouse button. The rectangle continues to stick to the mouse until I press the left mouse button again.
I have tried to prevent this behavior by catching the 'mouse:down' event for the middle mouse button and calling 'event.e.preventDefault()', but this has not solved the problem.
Has anyone else ever experienced this problem or have suggestions on how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your support.
Best regards, Mike
